# Stop Threadx scheduler

Tags: stm32, bootloader, threadx, stm32h7

I am using Threadx on a STM H7 in a bootloader application.
Right before the jump into the application I want to make sure, the system is as clean as possible.
How do I stop the Threadx out of a running thread. So what I am looking for is something like DeinitThreadx().
I could stop, all threads manually besides the one I'm in. But how to handle the one I'm in?
Besides, I guess there is something more running in background isn't it?